# How to use gm convert to split a gif into multiple png files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, graphicsmagick, gm

I want to split `input.gif` into the files `output0.png` through `output15.png`.
Works perfectly fine in the terminal when I use this:

```
convert -coalesce input.gif output%d.png
```

But now I need to automate this across hundreds of files in specific folders using `gm` and I can not figure out how to make it work. You are supposed to use in() and out() to handle arguments, but it only ever outputs a single file named `output%d.png`

Can anyone with experience about gm help?

This is my current try:

```
gm("input.gif")
    .in("-coalesce")
    .out("output%d.png")
    .stream("png", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        // console.log(stdout)
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output%d.png");
        stdout.pipe(writeStream);
      });
```

Comment: Why are you even using Javascript? What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using javascript because the goal is to create a website with a node backend that can combine and separate gifs. It's also the language I'm most familiar with.